# Magento wordpress integration

Tags: magento, integration, blogs, fishpig

I'm using fishpig wp integration to magento.
I have blog.site.com and I want to keep this domain, while I'm using magento worpdress. 
How can I Integrate an existing WordPress blog and keep the same URL's. So that my  SEO will not be affected?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can integrate your existent wp blog in a new Magento store instance or integrate a new blog in an ancient store.

1. For integrate your wp blog in your Magento instance, you can declare blog.site.com as base_url (secure and|or insecure) in your magento store.

   - **Before that you must check in your wp blog if these urls like : catalog, checkout, admin, api, etc.. it's not already used.**
   - *You can retrieve every routings parameters in app/{pool}/{namespace}/{module_name}/etc/config.xml in [<frontend><routers><args<frontName>](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/module_config.xml#frontend) section*
2. After that, you have just to dump your wp db datas in your magento db.

   - *In my memories, I think it is possible to set up a prefix for the tables used by wp fishpig*